# Basic relationships between functions

Tags: calculus, functions, self-learning

I am working through the [Mooculus course](https://mooculus.osu.edu/exercises/functionTransformationPointwise). Can someone explain what is going on here?

The question:

> If f(2)=2 and g(x)=4⋅f(x), what point can you determine on the graph
>   of g?

This comes in the hint:

> You only have information about a point where x=2.
>
> At this point we have g(2)=4⋅f(2).
>
> Substituting f(2)=2 we have g(2)=4⋅2.
>
> So g(2)=8.
>
> Thus (2,8) is on the graph of g.

Thanks

Comment: what is not clear?

Comment: How exactly you get from `f(2)` to `(2,8)`. This is probably an example that makes a little more sense. There are others where I have less idea. In this example, where does the 2 in (2,8) come from? Is it from the f(2)? or somewhere else? Where does the 8 come from? I think it is making a bit more sense now, but an explanation would still be good. Thanks.

Comment: An example of one where I have no idea is `f(5)=−3 and f(x)=g(x−4)` where the answer is `(1,-3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $(1,-3)$ example:

You only know about the point $x=5$  so put $x=5$ into $f(x)=g(x−4)$.

Then $f(5)=g(5−4)=g(1)$.

So $g(1)=f(5)=-3$ and this gives you the point $(1,-3)$.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense for that equation. I think the problem that I am having is that they are asking the question in a variety of different ways.